# exporting Eclipse configuration

Tags: eclipse

I've invested a lot of time, sweat, hair and foul language getting my 32-bit Eclipse installation configured just how I like it, with lots of plugins like Maven,  MAT and TPCP .

Now the time has come to switch over to 64-bit. Can one export/import an Eclipse installation configuration in the same way one can export/import a project?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following wizards...

File -> Import -> Install -> From Existing Installation

File -> Import -> Install -> Install Software Items From File

File -> Export -> Install -> Installed Software Items to File

The first one is likely the easiest approach. Just get yourself a new base Eclipse, run it and point that wizard at your old install.

Comment: The first might not work, if the new Eclipse version is a different one, as it really tries to load exactly those existing local plugins (I was told). Using the slightly longer way with export/import to/from file gives you the ability to _upgrade_ those plugins to their latest versions during the process.

Comment: If you do see that behavior, I would recommend opening a bug. I don't see a rational reason for why those two wizards should behave differently. If there is a need to allow newer version to be discovered, that should be specified by a checkbox in either wizard.